# Jquery find vs id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am looking for the quickest way of getting access to an element.

What is quicker:

```
$('body').find('#elemID');
```

vs.

```
var id = $('#elemID');
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you're not genuinely concerned about performance.

Comment: The 2nd one is quicker, but the 1st is quicker than `$("body #elemId")`.  Run some tests on jsperf and see for yourself (they're probably already there)

Comment: You're using jQuery so performance is a little moot (at least to the point of worrying over which selector is faster). However the latter is  faster as there's only one DOM access. The former is redundant anyway, as there should only ever be one element with that `id` in the DOM.

Comment: I wouldn't worry to much about the microbenchmarking. There are almost certainly better places to focus your attention if you are concerned about performance. document.getElementById() is probably faster than both (and you didn't pay to load jquery) for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Document.getElementById()` is fastest of all, and doesn't require jQuery.  Then, you have the option of wrapping it in jQuery using the `$`, if and when you need jQuery functionality.

Comment: If anyone was wondering, this is about 40% faster in Chrome on Win10: https://jsperf.com/jquery-object-from-selector-or-element-object/1. jQuery can still do ~2.5m ops/sec though, so it's not exactly a critical difference which is worth creating more verbose code.

Comment: damn i just got my own answer unaccepted xD its only fair

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer is that it doesn't matter but if you have to choose one anything other than the first.

if you're worried about performance look for bottlenecks, not micro-optimizations.

Try to use vanilla js if possible but if you're using Jquery might aswell get the most from it.

```js
const body = () => $('body').find('#elemID');
const id = () => $('#elemID');

const idJs = () => document.getElementById('elemID');

function performanceCalc(fn, params) {
    const start = new Date()
    const result = fn()
    const end = new Date()

    console.log(`Result: ${result} ${params}. Execution Time: ${end - start} ms`)
}

performanceCalc(body, 'body')

performanceCalc(id, 'id')

performanceCalc(idJs, 'idJs')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="elemID"></div>
```